# Using RegEx to extract digital number from the innertext of a webpage element

Tags: c#, regex

I used the regex of  `(?:\[+\.)?\d+` to extract the digits from the innertext of the website element, the innertext was `$94.99/mo`.

This worked and I can create a variable equal to `105.66`. When I apply this regex to innertext which has different digital values contained in it, than all the digital values are selected.

e.g.

> Total Monthly Payment: $94.99 + $9.49 (for ASP) = $104.48/month (plus
>   tax) • Total Cost of Ownership: $104.48 x 12 Months = $1,253.76 (plus
>   tax) • Cost of Lease Services: $350.77

It finds all the values;
How do I modify the regex so that it only finds the `9.49` price?

Comment: I'd use [`\$(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+\(for\s*ASP\)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%24(%5cd%2b(%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b)%3f)%5cs*%5c(for%5cs%2bASP%5c)&i=Total+Monthly+Payment%3a+%2494.99+%2b+%249.49+(for+ASP)+%3d+%24104.48%2fmonth+(plus+tax)+%e2%80%a2+Total+Cost+of+Ownership%3a+%24104.48+x+12+Months+%3d+%241%2c253.76+(plus+tax)+%e2%80%a2+Cost+of+Lease+Services%3a+%24350.77) and use `match.Groups[1].Value` to get the number.

Comment: I will try this suggestion, it looks good but will proof in my application ASAP and then add further comment, thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually, I posted the comment because you did not specify the requirements. This regex will match a price begore a " (for ASP)" substring.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to extract this: `+ $9.49`
You can use following regex:

```
@"(?<=\+\s\$)(\d+\.?\d*)
```

- `(?<=\+\s\$)` match but don't include a `+` followed by a whitespace, followed by a `$`
- `(\d+\.?\d*)` match and put in a group at least one digit, followed by an optional `.` followed by any number of digits.

The `+ . $` signs are special regex characters which have to be escaped with a backslash.

Comment: I used the string prompt of (?<=\+\s\$)(\d+\.?\d*) worked excellently and returned the value I was looking for.

Comment: @Eamo Remember to accept/upvote an answer if it helped you :)